# Moving Data from MS Access to MS Excel

Tags: ms-access

I have the following code that will take information from a form in Access and populate rows in a Excel file under the corresponding header. My question is, is there a better way to code this then the way that I have? I noticed everytime it opens it moves to the next line, which is good. But if I had to back out of Excel and change info from the form it will still go to the next line. Also is there some code I could add to refresh/delete my Excel file after 30 rows have been populated?

```
Private Sub Command73_Click()
Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objXLBook = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open("Y:\123files\Edmond\Hotel Reservation Daily.xls")
objXLApp.Application.Visible = True

i = i + 1

objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = Me.GuestFirstName & " " & GuestLastName
objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = Me.PhoneNumber
objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = Me.cboCheckInDate
objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 4).Value = Me.cboCheckOutDate
objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = Me.GuestNo
objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 6).Value = Me.RoomType
objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 7).Value = Me.RoomNumber
objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 8).Value = Date
objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 9).Value = Me.Employee
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [TransferSpreadsheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220766%28office.11%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

How about you just add the values to a Table in Access and have the Excel file just linked to the table?

and the 30 records.

- if you have a script for deleting the table when it reaches 30 records
- or just keep all the records and have Excel linked to the TOP 30 Items???

Lastly, if you're using Access to ONLY populate Excel with these 30 values and, say, have reoccuring Excel docs, you could do the work directly in Excel and have Excel pump the data into Access.

- i.e. Create a template Excel doc with proper columns
- create a script that adds the values from each row into your Access table